# angular-ui shift button keypress

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I've managed to get enter keypress to work.  But I can't seem to get the "shift" button keypress to work. Here is my code for enter:

```
<button 
    class="btn btn-primary order-input-add" 
    ui-keypress="{13:'add_plu(order.orderwindow.add_field)'}" 
    ng-click="add_plu(order.orderwindow.add_field)">Add
</button>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like there is anything built into ui.keypress to handle a shift by itself - it seems to only work as a modifier key: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils/blob/master/modules/keypress/keypress.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems that you can't capture a shift key press by itself using ui.keydown (if so, probably because it's most often used as a modifier key), you can instead create your own directive that decorates an element to listen for shift on the keydown event:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('captureShift', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem[0].onkeydown = function(){
        console.log('shift pressed');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Shift doesn't seem to fire on keypress but does on keydown, so `onkeydown` is used.

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/78L1bWRVwJsxroOjWTxR?p=preview)